# How to replicate web browsers in unreal engine?

Tags: browser, replication, unreal-engine5

I have a 3d widget that contains a web browser. I need to replicate the web browser content on the client side. I need whatever changes that are made to the web browser on the server side to be synced with all the clients. For example, if a youtube video is loaded on the server, I want all the clients to be able to watch it through the same replicated web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a replication project with Web Browsers and Video Streaming in general for the last couple of weeks. As far as I'm aware, you can't actually "replicate" it because the Web Browser Plugin (the normal one that UE has without needing to download it from the Marketplace) is pretty much an unfinished prototype that lacks a lot of control. Rather, you can replicate it but it won't work, so to say. It just means it does the functions it's supposed to do instead of anything being shared across clients and the server.

What you can do instead is actually Execute Javascript commands from inside your Web Browser Widget, which you call from your Actor Blueprint or Character Blueprint with Multicast Events.

Just to make it simpler, what you can do is send a "request" to the server if the Actor you're using the event from isn't a Server (UE4 has an "isServer" boolean you can call from pretty much anywhere), and then actually execute that with a Multicast Event if it is a Server.

Another difficult part about it is the fact that you can't really achieve Sound Attenuation with Browsers unless you brute-force it with Sphere/Box Collisions and the Youtube API which lets you change the volume of the Youtube video.

For more information about using Multicasts properly, I suggest you to look at this [blog](https://vorixo.github.io/devtricks/stateful-events-multiplayer/). Didn't understand a lick until I read this.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth info. I’m very new to ue5 and I’m having trouble figuring out the Java script commands inside the browser widget and how I can call those inside the blueprint. Haven’t been able to find any tutorials on this matter. I would really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: What I did is just use a "template" HTML that has a div with an ID on it, which I got from a Youtube iframe API tutorial, then ended up using Javascript to control the Youtube iframe. Take a look at their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

As for how to use it in UE, you just open the Widget in which you added your Web Browser, then turn that into a variable. After turning that into a variable (it should have a checkbox near the name), get it in the Blueprint and drag a line out of it. There should be an "Execute Javascript" node.

Comment: Oh, also, in case you don't know how to access the Blueprint portion of a widget, just look at the top right corner. There should be a button that says "Graph" on it.